# SCCM 2012 OSD Task Sequence - Rename computer with Service Tag

Tags: sccm

I am planning to deploy Windows 10 using SCCM 2012. It is working fine, and now I just want to rename the computer to be same as its DELL service tag, and make it as part of Task Sequence. I would ideally like to use Powershell script to do so, however happy to use VBS as well, in case it isn't easy enough with PS.

Following is the Powershell script that does the job, however I can't add it as part of Task Sequence!

```
$sTag = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_BIOS | Select SerialNumber
$cName = 'DESKTOP' + $sTag.SerialNumber
Rename-Computer -NewName $cName
```

Can someone please assist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that a different kind of approach would be easier so I posted this as an answer, however technically your way should work so I am not sure what the problem even is. In case your problem is not the code but some error message or how to run the powershell commands you might run into the same problems with my answer. If this is so just let me know so I can maybe expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off not renaming the computer after it is already present in sccm and ad but give it a proper name before it is joined (assuming you use unknown computer support for the osd here)

In this case you should set the SCCM Variable OSDCOmputerName already within the WinPE phase like this (you can find more detailed examples e.g. [here](http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2013/06/03/automate-computer-name-during-osd-in-configmgr-2012-with-powershell/)):

```
$sTag = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_BIOS | Select SerialNumber
$OSDComputerName = 'DESKTOP' + $sTag.SerialNumber
$TSEnv = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment 
$TSEnv.Value("OSDComputerName") = $OSDComputerName
```

If you want to use powershell in PE you will have to modify your boot image (Right click --> Properties --> Optional Components) to include "Windows PowerShell"

Comment: Thanks for the reply Syberdoor.. This worked like charm. :)